# Multi-Booted Ubuntu, Win7, Win10 - Windows 10 boot menu not working correctly

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot, grub, dualboot

A few weeks ago I multi-booted my computer with Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Windows 10. It has been working fine until now. Here is the issue:

1. I turn on my computer and the GRUB 2 OS select screen appears. There are the following options (I have excluded Ubuntu advanced options etc.):

   - Ubuntu
   - Windows recovery options
   - Windows 10
2. I choose Windows 10 and Windows 10's OS select screen comes up. It has these options:

   - Windows 10 Pro
   - Windows 7 Home Premium
   - Ubuntu
3. When I choose any option the computer restarts and I am back on the GRUB menu. The only way to boot Windows is to choose Windows recovery options from GRUB menu. When I do that the Windows version (7 or 10) that I chose on step 2 (that is, *if* I chose a windows version on step 2) boots. How can I make it so that the option I choose on step 2 boots straight away when I choose it Windows menu?

EDIT: My computer has a BIOS, not a UEFI

EDIT 2: This issue happened after I did an auto fix using the Windows installation media. Before that I couldn't boot Windows at all.

Comment: Have you compared the entries for recovery and non-recovery entries in Grub? Unless configured otherwise using `e` (IIRC) you should be able to see and edit the currently selected boot entry. As it stands this question has too little information to answer beyond pure guessing.

Comment: @ArcaEgeCengiz edit your question and add the part of grub config file relating to those entries

Comment: also check this out : https://askubuntu.com/a/758632

Comment: What do you mean @0xC0000022L?

Comment: @ArcaEgeCengiz I don't know how to be clearer. But your comment suggests that the Windows "fix" is causal to the issue, so I suggest you boot your Ubuntu media, mount the root, `/boot`, `/dev`, `/proc` etc in order to chroot into it and then install GRUB from within Ubuntu ...